# Make two vimeo videos side by side, centered, and responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vimeo-player

I have to Vimeo videos, and I am trying to make them sit side by side and centered in the body whenever a computer is viewing them. Then whenever a small screen (like an iPhone) is viewing them, I want the right one to drop beneath the left one and fit the size of the body.

Here is what I have so far. HTML:

```
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
    <div class="vimeo-video-1 vimeo-standard">
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen align="middle" seamless></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo-video-2 vimeo-standard">
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen align="middle" seamless></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vimeo-standard {
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    float: left;
}
.vimeo-video-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.vimeo-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .vimeo-standard {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16/9 ratio */
        padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .vimeo-video-2 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .vimeo-standard iframe, .vimeo-standard object, .vimeo-standard embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .vimeo-standard iframe {
        width: 352px;
        height: 198px;
    }
    .vimeo-standard {
        width: 352px;
    }
    .vimeo-video-2 {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

I have created some responsive CSS for it, but I am having trouble getting to just right so that it is centered, responsive, and side-by-side when it is fullscreen.

What should I change the HTML and CSS to for it to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your `css`, it is less now and fully responsive. I have added some extra `borders` so you can identify the boundaries of each div you have inside your markup, you may remove them.

the key to center items inside a container is to give `position:relative` and `margin:0 auto`

And yeah, whenever you need to use floating objects inside a container you need to use `clearfix` so that container may reset its `height` property

[Check it at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahj6h/)

```
 .vimeo-wrapper {
        max-width: 980px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .vimeo-standard {
        float: left;
        height: 300px;
        width: 47%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    @media (max-width:767px) {

        .vimeo-standard {
            float: none;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```